# android studio 3.0 Canary 1 : project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

I tried to load my project in this new **Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1**.
It was running perfectly in my previous **Android Studio Version 2.4 preview 7**

This is the error I am facing:

```
Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':sample:devCompileClasspath'.
Project :sample declares a dependency from configuration 'devCompile' to configuration 'dev' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :library.
```

My gradle configs are as below:

**Project Level Build Gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Library Module Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

android {
    publishNonDefault true

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME
        versionCode project.VERSION_CODE.toInteger()
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'AUTHORS'
        exclude 'NOTICE'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }

        dev.initWith(buildTypes.debug)

        staging.initWith(buildTypes.debug)

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

def ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION = "25.3.1"
def OK_HTTP3_VERSION = "3.6.0"
def GLIDE_VERSION = "3.7.0"
def GSON_VERSION = "2.8.0"
def AWS_KINESIS_VERSION = "2.4.2"
def PLAY_SERVICE_VERSION = "10.2.4"

dependencies {
    compile(name: 'library-release', ext: 'aar')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$OK_HTTP3_VERSION"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:$OK_HTTP3_VERSION"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$OK_HTTP3_VERSION"
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$GSON_VERSION"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$PLAY_SERVICE_VERSION"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$PLAY_SERVICE_VERSION"
    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$GLIDE_VERSION"
    checkstyle('com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:7.6.1')
    compile "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-kinesis:$AWS_KINESIS_VERSION"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    showViolations = true
    configFile file("config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")

    description 'applies the checkstyle config to the java files'
    source 'src/main/java'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'

    // empty classpath
    classpath = files()
}

preBuild.dependsOn('checkstyle')
```

**App Module Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.and"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME
        versionCode project.VERSION_CODE.toInteger()
        android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }

        dev.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }

        staging.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        staging {
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        }

        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../library/libs'
    }
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    releaseCompile
    stagingCompile
    devCompile
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    releaseCompile (project(path: ':library', configuration: 'release')) {
        transitive = true
    }
    stagingCompile (project(path: ':library', configuration: 'staging')) {
        transitive = true
    }
    devCompile (project(path: ':library', configuration: 'dev')) {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

Did anyone face the same issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the migration tips:
[Use Flavor Dimensions for variant-aware dependency management](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#variant_aware)

As it states:

> Plugin 3.0.0 includes a new dependency mechanism that automatically
>   matches variants when consuming a library. This means an app's debug
>   variant automatically consumes a library's debug variant, and so on.
>   It also works when using flavors—an app's redDebug variant will
>   consume a library's redDebug variant. To make this work, the plugin
>   now requires that all flavors belong to a named flavor dimension —even
>   if you intend to use only a single dimension. Otherwise, you will get
>   the following build error:

```
Error:All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension. 
The flavor 'flavor_name' is not assigned to a flavor dimension.
```

> To resolve this error, assign each flavor to a named dimension, as
>   shown in the sample below. Because dependency matching is now taken
>   care of by the plugin, you should name your flavor dimensions
>   carefully. For example, if all your app and library modules use the
>   foo dimension, you'll have less control over which flavors are matched
>   by the plugin.

```
// Specifies a flavor dimension. flavorDimensions "color"

 productFlavors {
      red {
       // Assigns this product flavor to the 'color' flavor dimension.
       // This step is optional if you are using only one dimension.
       dimension "color"
       ...
     }

     blue {
       dimension "color"
       ...
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  flavorDimensions "mode"
productFlavors {
    dev {
        // Assigns this product flavor to the "mode" flavor dimension.
        dimension "mode"
        versionName "1.2"
        versionCode 02
    }
    uat {
        // Assigns this product flavor to the "mode" flavor dimension.
        dimension "mode"
        versionName "1.2"
        versionCode 2
    }
    live {
        // Assigns this product flavor to the "mode" flavor dimension.
        dimension "mode"
        versionName "1.0.1"
        versionCode 01
    }
}
```

This is working for me !!
In your case you should just make a flavorDimensions variable and assign the value inside the dev block

***flavorDimensions "anyvalue"***

dev.initWith(buildTypes.debug)

```
    dev {
        dimension "anyvalue"
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }
```

This should help .

Comment: Note that you also need to define that dimension type in the level above `productFlavors`. Like so:

    flavorDimensions "mode"
    productFlavors { ... }