# Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I having problem to compile new gradle as shown below here :

> Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-studio-preview/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta2/gradle-3.0.0-beta2.pom
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-studio-preview/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta2/gradle-3.0.0-beta2.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta2/gradle-3.0.0-beta2.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta2/gradle-3.0.0-beta2.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :
>   Open File

This is my gradle :

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-2'
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android studio 3.0 Canary 1 : project refresh failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039762/android-studio-3-0-canary-1-project-refresh-failed)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1 in circle ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071080/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-0-alpha1-in-circle-ci)

Answer (score 8):

You have to add the gradle maven repo:

```
 maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

Something like:

```
buildscript {
    //..
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    //..
}
```

You can also use the google() shortcut if you are using Android Studio 3.x and gradle v.4

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta-2'
    }
}
```

Comment: For me it worked just by adding google(), but for example, if I was using Android Studio 2.x, will it work with google()? Or do I have to add the maven repo?

Comment: @HyunJin in my experience it requires gradle plugin 3.3, gradle v.4 and Android Studio v.3.x. May be it can also work with the latest Android Studio 2.3 but always with plugin 3.3 and gradle v.4

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding depemdency in this manner-

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta4' 

}
```